# Could $\sum e^{a_i}$ be simplified? Does it have an identity?

Tags: summation, exponentiation

$\sum_{i=1}^n e^{a_i}$ (where $a_i \in \mathbb R$) is expensive for large $n$ (a sum and $n$ exponential operations). I was wondering if there is any way for simplifying this?

Comment: What are your $a_i$?

Comment: $a_i$ could be any random real number.

Comment: What are your $\,a_i$'s...and what does it mean a series is "expensive"?

Comment: Sorry for using bad terminology. I mean computing the results requires many operations ($n$ exponentiation). I am looking for a faster way to compute the result.

Comment: So we could have $a_i = \log(b_i)$ for any sequence $b_i$?  Then you're asking if there's a way of summing $n$ arbitrary numbers without actually adding them up?

Comment: I don't think that there is, in general, any way to decrease the number of exponential operations needed.

Comment: There's no real way to avoid lots of exponentiation calls unless you have nice properties on the $a_i$.

Comment: Thank you for the explanations. I wonder why that is that there is no way to decrease the number of exponential operations required.

Comment: How are the exponential operations being performed? There may be ways to improve the speed based on reformulation in terms of the operation itself.

Comment: @Tim: It's not the additions that are the issue, I think. In your argument, the point would be that evaluating the $b_i$ values themselves is the hard part. ssi is asking if there's a way to reduce the number of exponentiation operations, like you can reduce the number of 8 bit multiplication operations when multiplying large numbers.

Comment: If this were a well-defined sequence there might be a way to reduce the number of additions...but if it's an arbitrary sequence then there's probably no way.

Comment: @GlenO I'm not sure if I correctly understand your question, I have not implemented the operations yet, but I think I will use the standard library of any language I use. Your question gave me an idea that I could probably minimize the operations by looking into how my compiler calculates the exponential operations.

Comment: If you work only with limited precision, another issue may be that you should add in the right order (from small $a_i$ to big) to avoid errors. On the other hand if some (but not too many) $a_i$ are a lot smaller than others, you may ignore their summands altogether.

Comment: @ssi: My first suggestion would be to test whether the "cost" of the operation depends on the size of $a_i$. If it gets larger for values of $a_i$ of higher magnitude, then it may be worth sorting the $a_i$ values in order of magnitude, and then evaluating them sequentially (that is, evaluate $e^{a_{i+1}-a_i}$ and then use multiplication from there).

Comment: I'll write that up as an answer, to make it clearer.

Answer (score 1):

One possible way to reduce the cost of the exponentiation operation may be to replace exponentiation involving large exponents with multiplications. This is what I mean:

Assume that $\{a_i\}$ is sorted in ascending order (if not, sort them first), so that $a_{i+1}\geq a_i$. Now, let's use the notation
$$
A(n) = \sum_{i=1}^n e^{a_i}
$$
Obviously, $A(1)=e^{a_1}$. Now, we can write
$$
A(2)=A(1)+e^{a_2}
$$
But we could also write this as
$$
A(2) = A(1)+b_1e^{a_2-a_1}
$$
where $b_1=e^{a_1}$. Similarly, we have
$$
A(3)=A(2)+b_2e^{a_3-a_2}
$$
where $b_2=e^{a_2}=b_1e^{a_2-a_1}$. If we define the sequence
$$
b_{i+1} = e^{a_{i+1}-a_i}b_i
$$
with $b_1=e^{a_1}$, then we can write
$$
A(n+1)=A(n)+b_{n+1}
$$
The advantage of this is that, while $a_n$ may be very large, and thus require a lot of computation, it may be much quicker to calculate the various $b_i$. It requires just as many exponentiation operations, but reduces the size of the exponent significantly, which may save on operation cost.

However, it is subject to the exponentiation cost relationship. If the cost of exponentiation remains almost constant with size of the exponent, then this will actually be slower than simply evaluating the exponentials directly, due to the added multiplications.

Comment: @ssi - Have you tested the cost of exponentiation, yet? If not, I suggest you unmark it as the correct answer for the time being, as it may not be of any help to you.

Comment: I have to leave right now to see a friend urgently - I will create the tests when I'm back. Sorry for the delay

Comment: My benchmarks run in Ruby (MRI v1.9.3) and JavaScript (NodeJS v0.10.5) showed that the performance of computing $e^{a_i}$ is not related to the size of $a_i$.

Comment: Computing 50,000,000 operations for $−700.0<a_i<700.0$ on my computer takes $2.16 \pm 0.03$ seconds. For larger values it returns $\infty$ or 0.

Comment: Well, that's unfortunate. It means that there's no reformulation that will accelerate the code as it currently stands. There may, however, be other methods of accelerating the code. How accurate does the exponential have to be? Do you need it at maximum accuracy, or just a good estimate? There are methods that can increase speed by a reasonable factor at the cost of reducing accuracy, for instance.

Comment: Just a good estimate would be fine for what I am doing right now.  (Actually, I just need a continuous bell-like function, ie always zero except in the middle. I'm using the Gaussian function, and that's why I have to optimize the exponentiations.)

Comment: Btw, I really appreciate your answer very much because it is a very interesting approach and might work in other cases that I have not tested yet. Thank you.

Comment: In that case, perhaps something like [this](http://robowiki.net/wiki/Thread:User_talk:Rednaxela/FastTrig/Fast_gaussian_kernel_function) may help - it uses a trick explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10552280/) and should be within about 4% of the correct value.

Comment: Thank you, this is really useful :)